# How to configure HandlerMethodArgumentResolver in spring boot test

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-mvc-test, spring-boot-test

I am writing a unit for a controller with spting boot `@WebMvcTest`.

Using `@WebMvcTest`, I will be able to inject a `MockMvc` object as given below :-

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
@WebMvcTest
class MyControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void my_controller_test() throws Exception {
       mockMvc.perform(post("/create-user"))
              .andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }
}
```

In the controller I am injecting a `Principal` argument using spring `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. Please inform me how can I write a unit test with `MockMvc` , so that I can inject a mock `Principal` object as the argument in the controller method.

The sction [Auto-configured Spring MVC tests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests) explains that the Test annotated with `@WebMvcTest` will scan beans of `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. So I created a bean which extends `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and return the mock `Principal` object as below .

```
@Component
public class MockPrincipalArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
   @Override
   public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
     return parameter.getParameterType().equals(Principal.class);
   }

   @Override
   public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter...) throws Exception {
     return new MockPrincipal();
   }
 }
```

But still the Argument `MockPrincipal` is not getting passed to controller method.

Spring boot version :- 1.4.5.RELEASE

Comment: You need to specify the principal on the request you are making, not create an additional `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. `post(/your-url).principal(new MockPrincipal())`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I wasted time unnecessary looking other options :).  If you don't mind could you please mention, where it is documented ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `MockMvc` to call your controller. With that you have to prepare the request with things like parameters, body, URL and also the principal. What you don't specify won't be included (you are now basically doing a call without an authenticated principal).

The Spring MVC  Testing support for [MockMvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-test-server) is documented, in general, in the reference guide.

For more detailed info check the component that is used for building a mock request the [`MockHttpServletRequestBuilder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.html). Which is what your `post` method will return, which should be a call the `MockHttpServletRequestBuilders.post` (and probably a static import in your code). A [CTRL]+[SPACE] (or whatever your favorite code completion short cut is in your iDE) after `post()` will give you some insight in what is available.

```
@Test
public void my_controller_test() throws Exception {
   mockMvc.perform(post("/create-user").principal(new MockPrincipal())
          .andExpect(status().isCreated());
}
```

Something like the above should do the trick.